# Caching seems to be breaking my website and i don't know where to look

Tags: caching, cache-control, w3-total-cache

Hoping someone here can assist with giving me a few ideas on what to check and where to look with a new issue I have.

I have implemented W3TC Caching on a website to improve loading times but it has created a problem with page loading - the pages now load garbled text on first load and then after refresh it seems to work fine.

I am 99% sure it's W3TC because when I clear the cache, the issue happens and then after a refresh, it goes away.

This is what is displayed before refreshing:

����v�'����"fd��t�o�o���<{Jz�F'ؼ�Tʡ ���>����ꛯ�EM����7ֈ��e����l{��#�ƛ��oA�
G�b�r,��z�U�]�3e��<����`hI���2�,�Z�}RuO�i��Ck�T,����|^�q�~�F#M�R�E$k�k4��c��b��ޔ�C�����F�gc���#/H}V���AM�2�ӡE��"u�Zz  �U���tFM�Ed��qduڞ3��@�����
��{ޔ&��������GJM;�b��)�
��oN�3�Tq7`ɦZϞ�?aUo���
k�h�!A��D�CF�Y?�ȟ��?O8�5X@*')+?.د��!����V�Q�q6�E�
0s���g3�1[�T    �Nq�ң��beLq"��^YhhƓ�H&�O��8Zn�1�2�znon�� ��Z<�W�0�L��̖0ܞ����GqhQ�]g��U�z�}�����'��'��UG����gS��������o��*`�3N=E��!i�,��\�ĝ�
d�C�F"
�۳���e�U�H�1�bʛV�J�>`Y3�Әk$����9��Q�$��厁�q�    ��Hy�.�vh]'�(�SqL�Z�m�è5�wL,�Bޑ@/����ʷV�����٦V�
ίB2=�nR#���4��b�J�B�Ë��{go�4R���,�g�d���V��خ�j͊V%����V��V���1�ɇ{������Q�Ѩ�?�(��ڃ�^���4�    0T��E?�N�[�D��W�H�Q�x/����S��7��m69�dr�.��Ǘ���,~�C6fRm"��m�C�΢�,"�id% ��U2F+�����h o/hU�&�J�^N�Z�,�@$�s�"M"v�Y�[f��0G�N��B0�����Ci���� 5��&k�����`�F�r���*��jR����g���v��
�{�W�=�T��09�o�wC���e9���l�}��/_޾{\�S9=��$����ת����DlN����!�0xy0<��!4N��Z䏋�t��.�{�xwLkT."o��&���@_H�A8,Q?2P
;@��>>����*��45Պ�A�ZZrY�9�:̬��K������  =�����n����]ہw�*��H�:��t�0���B¯�a���Q�mW>c�:ID�G��1;=�T���0!��"�1 �X}}0Bm�!�����;_k2��'<R�qY�'ё�`�W L�sR7�7W��|߇�ۊ�1�Kfg�"�P�}�Cb׷�3A����wk��b   d����s��ϸL��Ŕ��*���6���-�^0���&�e$� �  ��<�F�ZO�x��V�!��Y�N$���A�.�s�1������~T�OE���g�����s�������2&l1���DB�EB�B9O#����#r��F��{]ⴻ'u7cpxũW�[fo�MSH���%Uz/cH�Wc�e�����֥*:M�M[��2�w[�͌(B?:��-���������8�o��N�֓^�^.'��EL�e����4z6sڽ^�iz�^�S��  �r탇֠m����"ˆ�q���@,\���H�,g)<��t���`�Ԉ+֢�>�7�f,�ݨ���j-�Y��JLpEC�u<�5������V��2��՚/���ze�n^�E�47���^O���r  b)`�4`^��B��Z%ֱ���1��ћ]��C�Hh�ݪM�����F?#��o"���%Ո�.tR�fP{��[���T�6�S��Iy��p����H��k^�e�����O��[U�����S;�β��+ݪ��.Dw?~h�27��F�t;�Ӹ/S���L�1�X�����\������/�~|�T莥JR�_�{ ���y3+��
��p���7�h|�c��&b���z�2��-S��3��  �J$�4`��ɫUۊ�z\o��?��w�wd�n��O�q�ݺ��]ݻa!a�����[}�Nc.���1cI�[n ����Vv��t���0?��E�4�J�n�h�qԐ۹@M1�臭���Ku���� ��k��g&t��s���ػ���nyk݋�b�4i���fn�����{���T^�F�Z�V]� �{i��>{��/�Oy�l搗��2)wa|yd�֮k
w����N�]UaLme�
�V����q*�폋@y��"V��d��2������K{'4Q�6�1��R^�:o�"&FQ�$U����
���)���ڔ
��Y�IW�H�#�-E��HK��6���I<:�ㄆlOW0A�"�1G�q��"�����nHc���p�    �>~4ᣵ��-������7��N����a�Ys��n�1/���[�����A�i5z�^��k�7���߄-�R�4���&�u����Ӫ9�p�'�����6p�p��ߢ�����'���N{ܣ�n�ў�ߔ��y�j�s����ͳ��
��K�|8�׳�Ö�kc�i
����wXF�d���~{�������5�e�j�������-[#ӡ��Z���� �^�X���Ђ�B��3m��~IcU �f5(���4P��J��ERI�����FD4�<�:�~$�⧛�a�-�;/��Ƞ��&(m
��Ͱ��~a3�J�):�q�z�A�2`��&�heTeT�§��]�?]>�E䣝j!ƣ�_�v�8-�t�i���s1��%��Up�M��C�����T�0^��\��(���.��q�9(���zK�v���h����T� "����2�hUPTɇf����<�M�Q����'���,bh)s���.Q���p�^�Dv"SۿC��r��qfpo9�&��:�%�-�W����ư�.U�u������ʜr�4a4T ���QE֎Qzw:F)}f���c��4�^��IX���,8��r�Y��.̳5��m�L@+���+a��Om����[=    V��$Dx��'c���E����y�J�7�E��q�ٱ�S��I|�;Pkg8�Yۉ�X#�2�����NJ��2�y�6�Td�B�,�P� �*t4�猒,^�\�]pĎ��N�j��0�����ˌg���+�aNX�5���R��ld�֭97���ʢK덆�Ӥ���5~ ��[M�4X��X�u�ŉ+��n��
(���[�F'P`S6�j��)�9��k*�e �����[�
����d����hO�#m��>�౩t���<*h���ele!��L��`�M�V�3��+�٣F�=�/m*a�}Ly��M}��Z89\�o ��z�S߇�,w(��L{�qd@��FA�Y�o~iHۙ<B/l}@"H:��� �^���,c��n(
o�>�/I��c�㲨=��!WKm]���6q����M$6��Qۭ~_7�e�?�}��C,��HCR,���G�m�B��o�t�Uk-t�\QY��<�٧�e���E.��J�/!VC�����)�d�Y��
7/���ugm��#�-R\e�g��#����:2�|Y}�]���g`k������Ag���X<�6�<�kj�M�n�ݹ`�l�R�H��E�k/�h�K|��.q�.Q\|�Av���S�eQ�JR0���=�kR�뷌��F�]cu�m�v6����g*��  �`++�-hP��ܺOY�zm4�?�^Z���*�z���tzǒ�����&s��;�E�Oгi�w~��5��L|���{���4����ܾAzno��ۍmJ�����o)��s��nB���7�3S���r{�2�;��;��vroI�V�rj/����2I�E�oed٭Z��|�6k+߬�ܣ�O�4���!���ӛ_�-��7'��IlsEd���6F�òo�,&����Q�����pz����[��}��O��HRi�lF�?���gŹ�0�E�E}�\͚�$�D�c>�x;�*�O��~���?���REn>�Կ$G~B��[?I�iT���Fe4�  1{��g+a��7���g+���uH���,��?����K�d�,1�{*B!��Bլ�*���C>r�����}�?�ޚ�BVs��{��u�3 �{2��_*_F

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing happens when there's an issue with the content encoding, which is typically down to compression settings.

Usually either the `Content-Encoding` header is invalid or missing, or the `Vary` one is. I don't know W3TC, but a quick search for ["W3TC content encoding error"](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=w3tc%20content%20encoding%20error) brought up a few results, so fortunately this one is an issue that has [happened to a few people](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-content-encoding-error/).

## Apache default compression settings

Again I don't know W3TC, but from implementing similar caching setups, the first time it sees a request for a file which hasn't been cached yet, it'll build a .html file, compress it with something like gzip, and save it as a `.html.gz` file. Whenever a secondary request comes in, Apache can then directly serve up that static file as-is (knowing it's compressed already because of the file extension).

This issue occurs because it then *outputs the gzip data* to that first requester. By default, Apache compresses responses (unless it knows not to), so the result is it's being compressed twice.

So, the possible options:

- Turn off Apache's default compression settings by disabling `mod_deflate` on your website (Assuming all your requests go through W3TC anyway, this is probably the route W3TC would expect)
- Edit W3TC or your website by adding something like `apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1');` which has the same effect as the above but is more controllable as to which requests it applies to
- Turn off W3TC's compression (I wouldn't do this though; consider it a last resort!)